# update html table without updating page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a 1-120 table that is updated upon page refresh to change cell colours dependent on mysql values that are pulled in through a PHP file and an ajax request in the html but to update the table I have to have a force page refresh how can i change it so that just the cells update colours rather than refreshing the whole page? i did have in a meta tag with refresh option but ideally want it so only the table or even better just the table cells update as the php file does.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table Tracker</title>
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.0.5/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
<script>html5.addElements('latest_beacons')</script>
<![endif]-->
<script>

$(document).ready(function upateTable()(){
    for(var i=0; i < 12 ; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for(var j=1; j < 11 ; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i*10 + j}'>${i*10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/beacon.php',function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color',item.location);
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table id='zoning'>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to update the data automatically (comment in Elias answer), you can simply use `setInterval`, which in this case would update the data every 5 seconds:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
            for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
                $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
            }
        }

        $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var row;
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item);
                $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location);
            });
        });

        function upateTable() {
            $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
                response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    console.log(item);
                    $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location);
                });
            });
        }
        var updateTableInterval = setInterval(upateTable, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

If at some point you want to cancel the automatic refresh, you can clear the timer using:

```
clearInterval(updateTableInterval);
```

Comment: @eos sorry where would the go in my code i update it to your recommendation but it doesnt seem to update the cells as the php code updates?

Comment: I'd put it inside the `document.ready` function after your existing code. Btw: you can check the network tab in e.g. Chrome dev-tools to see if requests are made or not.

Comment: Okay that worked great however the table now gets added onto the bottom of the page each time how would i change that haha sorry for being a bit dumb with it all not great with it.

Comment: Post your updated code..probably you do `var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");` in the interval function callback.

Comment: i have edited my code the only bit i changed was adding in the LET part of your code and changing function to function updatetable()

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton: Well this can't work obviously :) I've edited my answer with the complete script..

Comment: @AvalonParkes-barton: You can accept my answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: sorry to re-open this topic so long after is there a way that i can update the cells back to grey after a certain period of time?